# How can I send GET values using jQuery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have code as below:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/Control/delete',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (bool) {
        if (bool == "deleted") {
            alert('record deleted');
            $(".row" + currentId).hide('slow');
        }
        else {
            alert('not deleted ');
        }
    }
});
```

Aay for example I need to send file_id (?file_id=12) paramater using GET, how can i do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `data` parameter

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: '/Control/delete',
  type: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: {file_id: 12}
  success: function (bool){
  if(bool == "deleted"){
    alert('record deleted');
    $(".row"+currentId).hide('slow');
  }
  else{
    alert('not deleted ');                  
  }
 }
});
```

Also not that `data` can be also a query string like:

```
data: "file_id=12&foo=bar"
```

In case if its not a query string, jQuery will automatically convert it to query string.

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string.

[jQuery.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `data` option:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  data: {file_id : 12},
  ......
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The actual GET method  `data: "file_id=12&someother=othervalue"`

Comment: Ok then how do you write a POST method

Comment: @ubercooluk: read the docs :) and what you say is another way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

Use this replace url with /url/delete?file_id=12

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/Control/delete?file_id=12',
      type: 'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      success: function (bool){
      if(bool == "deleted"){
        alert('record deleted');
        $(".row"+currentId).hide('slow');
      }
      else{
        alert('not deleted ');                  
      }
     }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add it to URL:

```
url: '/Control/delete?file_id=12',
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data` option of the ajax call and pass it an object with your key value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

```
//POST METHOD

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  data: {file_id : 12},
  ......
});

//GET METHOD

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  data: "file_id=12&someother=othervalue",
  ......
});
```